# Is it legal to camp on private property in Russia?

Tags: camping, legality, russia

In some places, like Scandinavia, you can camp pretty much anywhere you like as long as it's only for one night and you don't leave a mess.

> The freedom to roam, or everyman's right is the general public's right
>   to access certain public or privately owned land for recreation and
>   exercise. The right is sometimes called the right of public access to
>   the wilderness or the right to roam.

From [Wikipedia - Freedom to roam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam)

Is this also the case in Russia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know (living in Latvia, used to be a part of USSR), it is not completely legal. The owners can call the police, but it usually doesn't go that far.

If you try to camp in a field or near a private lake, try to talk to somebody, if a home is in sight. If not, people in these parts are quite forthcoming and I've yet to get more than a grumpy "Just pick up after yourself."

**A NOTE OF WARNING!** Making fire pits is a whole another matter. Doing that on a private property without permission might very well land you in jail, or in other kind of trouble.

***In short:*** Yes, but that doesn't stop decent people still doing it and living to tell the tale.